# How do I realize this 3 simple things in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

i am an absolute SQL beginner and i already did search a lot with google but didnt find what i needed. So how do i realize in SQL(translated from a ER-Model):

- An Entity having an Atribute that can have mulitple Entrys(I already found the ARRAY contstraint but i am unsure about that)
- An Entity having an Atribute that consists itself of a few more Atributes(Picture: http://static3.creately.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Attributes-ER-Diagrams.jpeg)
- Something like a isA Relation. And especially the total/partial and the disjunct characteristics.

Thanks already

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you have all three of this:

```
create table one 
(
  id integer primary key, 
  tags text[] -- can store multiple tags in a single column
);
```

A single column with multiple attributes can be done through a record type:

```
create type address as (number integer, street varchar(100), city varchar(100));

create table customer 
(
  id integer primary key, 
  name varchar(100) not null,
  billing_address address
);
```

An isA relation can be done using inheritance

```
create table paying_customer
(
   paid_at timestamp  not null,
   paid_amount decimal(14,2) not null
)
inherits (customer);
```

A paying customer has all attributes of a customer plus the time when the invoice was paid.

Comment: A related table is an alternate (more general and more standard) representation of an  attribute with multiple values.

Comment: @rd_nielsen: I would describe that as a one-to-many relationship (which is usually the way this is modelled. Also: arrays are part of the SQL standard (although with a slightly different syntax). An  "is A" relationship can also be modelled in a different way.